# Modified select in python django with icon

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a problem regarding python django templates and kinda lost on how to do that.
Can somebody help me on how im going to adjusting the css for  {{ poll_form.category }} (which is options list) and {{ poll_form.rating_option }} (options list) too. i want to put and icon on top of the options such as in facebook:

[image]

when i click the smile icon, there will be a dropdown option for my {{ poll_form.category }}.

below is what currently my form look like:

[image]

Ohh. somebody have any ideas or tutorial regarding this, do help or give me the link please..

Thank you in advance.

This is my form in home.html :

```
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body" >
                    {% for error in poll_form.non_field_errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                        {{ error }}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for field in poll_form %}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                        {{ field.label }} : {{ field.errors }}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    <form role="form" action="{% url 'home' %}" name="poll" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <p>
                                <label>Poll Category</label>
                                {{ poll_form.category }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-en">
                                <p>{{ poll_form.question_en }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                <label>Rating Options</label>
                                {{ poll_form.rating_option }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                <label>Poll Privacy</label>
                                {{ poll_form.privacy }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                <label>Image</label>
                                {{ poll_form.image }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                <br />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " name="poll">Launch and Share</button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```